# Airflow doesn’t see pandas

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

I have an issue with airflow, I definitely (100%) sure that the pandas is installed.
When I use pandas in the same file like

`if __name__ == '__main__':print(pd.DataFrame(data, columns))`

it works well but in WebUI Airflow there is an error:

```
Broken DAG: [PWD/aflow_stu/dags/amp_dag.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PWD/aflow_stu/dags/amp_dag.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pipelines import sql_engine, check_last_date, amp, amp_extract
  File "PWD/aflow_stu/dags/pipelines.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Don’t pay attention to PWD, just don't wanna post my folders.

The structure of `/dags` folder below:

```
dags/amp_dag.py
dags/pipelines.py #<- pandas is here
dags/api_services.py #<- api_methods for extracting data
```

So, do you guys know how to fix it?

Maybe I need to use another structure, traceback of python doesn’t see this error, why airflow see.

Comment: what executor do you use?

Comment: @rozumir 

`airflow config get-value core executor`

**SequentialExecutor**

Comment: Can you please tell where you have installed the airflow service?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, where do you see this error?  Is this:

a. when the tasks executes? Then the error would show in the logs. If this is the case, it's relevant also to know more about your setup and what kind of executor you use as @rozumir already asked. 
b. when the DAG parses. In this case, the error would show up at the home page of the the Airflow WebUI.

I am going to assume that it is B.
In this case you do not have pandas available in the Airflow virtual environment. If you are sure it is, I would recommend checking once more with what python paths you are running each. You can use the [sys.executable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) for this.

```py
import sys
raise ValueError(sys.executable)
```

Place these two lines at the top of your DAG file and make sure they return the same path. Only then you are 100% sure you are using the same virtual environment. If you still see a discrepancy, then also check `sys.path`.
If both are equal, pandas will for sure be available to both or neither as well.

Comment: I use SequentialExecutor

Comment: This error I see in UI airflow on `http://0.0.0.0:8080/home`
And airflow doesn’t see my dag.

Comment: I think Jorrick is correct here. I did encounter similar issues of what is mentioned here. When you dont have the packages installed in your airflow virtual environment, thats when you see the errors on the Airflow UI page when it tries to parse the dags. Make sure you have the pandas package installed in your Virtual Env